# Why does a reference to a variable behave as an array of size 1 sometimes?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void outputFirst(int x[]) {
    cout << x[0] << endl;
}

int main() {
    int x = 40;

    // works
    outputFirst(&x);

    // works
    int *y = &x;
    cout << y[0] << endl;

    // invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
    cout << &x[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why can I use a reference to an int as an array when I pass it to a function or assign it to another variable first, but not directly?

I'm using g++-6.3.

Comment: That is not a reference, it is a pointer.

Comment: Short answer: operator precedence.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry, that's what was taught in school. I guess I'll have to look up the correct terminology.

Comment: In C++ many things (including &) mean different thing in different context. In this case it is not a reference, but operator "take address of".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why can I use a reference to an int

Note that `&x` doesn't mean reference to `x`, it means [taking the address of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) `x` and you'll get a pointer (i.e. `int*`) from it. So `int *y = &x;` means taking the address from `x`, then `y[0]` means get the 1st element of the array pointed by the pointer (as if it points to the 1st element of the array which contains only one element (i.e. `x`) ), so at last it returns `x` itself.

And about why `&x[0]` doesn't work, note that `operator[]` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator&`. Then `&x[0]` is interpreted as `&(x[0])`, while `x[0]` is invalid since `x` is just an `int`.

You should add parentheses to specify the precedence explicitly, e.g.

```
cout << (&x)[0] << endl;
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Slava I tried to improve the answer; if it's still not complete enough, please tell me how to improve it more.

Comment: Your modification makes it better but I think it could be edited even more - to make main focus on explaining that this is not a reference, and then why last expression does not compile and how to fix it.

Comment: @Slava Fine, answer revised.